# Install Windows Server 2019 have disk driver issue

Tags: windows-server-2019

I have a ATA disk `ST4000NM0035 1V4` in my Dell server:

[image]

The server sees the disk in the BIOS

When I use my server to install Windows Server 2019, it will not recognize my 4T disk.

[image]

If the server sees the disk in the BIOS, is there a driver issue?

How can I solve this?

---

**EDIT-01**

I searched the dell support, get [this information](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=0r3ny), but there are `x.exe` files, can not execute when install the Windows Server.

Comment: The server/storage controller model is not provided, but in general you can get the required driver and add it to an ISO image: https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2019/07/add-drivers-to-a-windows-server-2019-iso-image/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to properly install such systems via idrac. During such provisioning via idrac kvm, idrac may provide you drivers. Probably you have problems with raid software driven shit controller, not the disk itself

Comment: I'm pretty sure the iDRAC is exclusive and proprietary to Dell, so I'm not sure how that's relevant to a SuperMicro server.

Comment: You are right. But provisioning system via BMC or so systems is just general idea. Maybe even your server has similar functions?

Comment: Yes, I'm just pointing out that someone with a SuperMicro server isn't going to know what you're talking about if you tell them to use the iDRAC.

Comment: yep, this is caused by raid software driver, but the .exe can not install when there is not a Windows system.

Answer (score 1):

Its a standard error. Please unpack your driver exe by loading the exe and copy the install folder after to use that for the install. The setup look for .drv, .dll and .inf for the driver name and corresponding hardware ID.